# Getting Image task to work in Ant

Tags: java, ant, jai

I'm trying to utilize the Image task in Ant, which requires Java Advanced Imaging.  The .jar file seems to be in the Ant library, but when I try to scale an image, it gives me the following error:

```
Could not load a dependent class javax/media/jai/PlanarImage
```

Is there a reason why the ant-jai.jar file wouldn't have this class already?  Does anyone have experience with using either JAI in Ant, or specifically in using the Image task successfully?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JAR contains only the objects defined in the [`Image task`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/image.html). You'll have to put JAI on your class path, too.

Addendum: Regarding `NoClassDefFoundError: javax.media.jai.OperationRegistrySpi`, you might verify that the class is in `jai_core.jar`, as shown below. One way to track down such anomalies is to use the `-verbose` option of the `java` command.

```
$ jar tf jai_core.jar | grep OperationRegistrySpi
javax/media/jai/OperationRegistrySpi.class

$ jar tf lib/ant-jai.jar 
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
org/
org/apache/
org/apache/tools/
org/apache/tools/ant/
org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/
org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/
org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/image/
org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/image/Image.class
org/apache/tools/ant/types/
org/apache/tools/ant/types/optional/
org/apache/tools/ant/types/optional/image/
org/apache/tools/ant/types/optional/image/Arc.class
org/apache/tools/ant/types/optional/image/BasicShape.class
org/apache/tools/ant/types/optional/image/ColorMapper.class
org/apache/tools/ant/types/optional/image/Draw.class
org/apache/tools/ant/types/optional/image/DrawOperation.class
org/apache/tools/ant/types/optional/image/Ellipse.class
org/apache/tools/ant/types/optional/image/ImageOperation.class
org/apache/tools/ant/types/optional/image/Rectangle.class
org/apache/tools/ant/types/optional/image/Rotate.class
org/apache/tools/ant/types/optional/image/Scale$ProportionsAttribute.class
org/apache/tools/ant/types/optional/image/Scale.class
org/apache/tools/ant/types/optional/image/Text.class
org/apache/tools/ant/types/optional/image/TransformOperation.class
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and I'll mark this as correct, but do you know why after putting JAI and JAI codec in the lib folder it's giving me the following: NoClassDefFoundError: javax.media.jai.OperationRegistrySpi

Comment: I'm not sure; but you can check `jai_core.jar` as suggested above.